# Why resizing an image in pillow isn't working?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm converting a gif into image sequences and that's working, but I want to resize the images then save them, I put the maximum width and height and I calculated the ratio and then resize the images, but the images are the same as before, here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image, GifImagePlugin

imageObject = Image.open("my.gif")

print(imageObject.n_frames, "frames")
print(imageObject.size)

count = 1
max_wh = 300 #the maximum height and width
width, height = imageObject.size
ratio = min(max_wh/width, max_wh/height)

print(height, width, ratio, int(width*ratio))

for frame in range(0, imageObject.n_frames):
    imageObject.seek(frame)
    imageObject.resize((int(width*ratio), int(height*ratio)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imageObject.save(f"a_{count}.png")
    count += 1
```

Comment: For the `imageObject.resize` line, can you put a breakpoint there and actually output what the arguments are, and see if it's the width and height values that you expect?

Comment: `.resize()` *returns a new image*.  You need to call `.save()` on *that*, not the original image.

Comment: @jasonharper yes that's the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: @RandomDavis jasonharper found the problem thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

From the [Pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize):

> Image.resize(size, resample=3, box=None, reducing_gap=None)
>
> Returns a resized copy of this image.

```
from PIL import Image, GifImagePlugin

imageObject = Image.open("my.gif")

print(imageObject.n_frames, "frames")
print(imageObject.size)

max_wh = 300 # the maximum height and width
width, height = imageObject.size
ratio = min(max_wh/width, max_wh/height)

print(height, width, ratio, int(width*ratio))

for frame in range(0, imageObject.n_frames):
    imageObject.seek(frame)
    # Image.resize() returns a resized copy of the original
    resized = imageObject.resize((int(width*ratio), int(height*ratio)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized.save(f"a_{frame}.png")
```